# How to to fix AWS Amplify Hosting Problems: "Your app has been built by Amplify Gen2 Please complete this flow in the new console"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am building an app with AWS Amplify Gen 1, everything so far has been built using the normal AWS Amplify console, however, when I try to host my app and connected it to the github repo I run into an error that says,

"Your app has been built by Amplify Gen2
Please complete this flow in the new console."

Up until now, my work has been exclusively on Generation 1. I don't remember working on Generation 2 since it was in beta when the project started. Given this situation, is there a method to verify which generation my project is on? I've gone through the documentation and conducted research but haven't found a solution other than transferring my source files to a new repository and setting up the Amplify connection from scratch, which I'd like to avoid. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Using the AWS CLI it did not directly indicate the generation.